# Swift package with pre-compiled dependency

Tags: swift, flurry, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to convert a custom analytics module (let's call it `Analytics`), which is a wrapper around the Flurry SDK, into a Swift package.

I got my package to find the Flurry header by creating a sub-package for Flurry with a custom `modulemap`. However, I don't know how I can statically link the Flurry library into the `Analytics` library exported by my package.

Is there a way to do that with Swift Package Manager yet?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way to do this at the moment without passing custom build flags. You will need to look at the `swiftc` flags and pass in the framework and module paths.